# jtextArea Prints 2 blank pages

Tags: java, printing, awt

I have a jTextArea that is filled with information that the program gives out, however, when i call the .print(); method, it prints 2 blank pages, it displays the popup and everything as other information shows on in the internet, I assume it does "see" the data in the text area since it wants to print two pages, but the problem is the pages just come out blank, any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
try {
      boolean complete = txaMainOutput.print();
        if(complete)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done Printing", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Printing", "Printer", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An Error has occured, looks like we could not print");
    }
```

https://gyazo.com/376958811a5fd9c5356843d8bf83c36f

Answer (score 0):

After Playing around with the code, I found that creating a new JTextArea, saving all the Origianal TextArea data to a string then setting the new TextArea to that string, and then printing it will resolve the problem of blank pages.

```
        String YourString = "Line 1 \nLine 2 \nLine 3" //define and set contents of your string - remember about formating with \n if you want to have it split on lines
        JTextArea YourTextArea = new JTextArea(); //define new Swing JtextArea
        YourTextArea.setLineWrap(true); //set line wrap for YourTextArea - this will prevent too long lines to be cut - they will be wrapaed to next line
        YourTextArea.append(YourString); //append YourString to YourTextArea
        YourTextArea.print(); //this will display print dialog that will lead you to print contents of YourTextArea so in efect contents of YourString
```